# Django Rest Framework router - exclude URL for prefix

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

I am using [DRF router with a prefix + include](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#using-include-with-routers) like this:

```py
router = BulkRouter()
router.register(r"myfeature", MyfeatureViewSet, base_name="myfeature")

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^api/1/", include(router.urls)),]
```

This allows me to hit the both `api/1` and `api/1/myfeature` URLS. How can I prevent the first URL from returning 200's? The response of that endpoint is a list of everything registered under the router which I don't want to make easily obtainable.

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(data='Not allow', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1) Wire a view directly to the prefix url (use the `$`)

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^api/1/$", some_view,
    url(r"^api/1/", include(router.urls)),]
```

2) Define the view.

There is a one-liner that Django provides - `django.views.defaults.page_not_found`. However, in newer versions of Django, this requires an exception parameter so you can't do it in a one-liner. Thus, we have something like this:

```py
def page_not_found_custom(request):
    return page_not_found(request, None)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^api/1/$", page_not_found_custom,
    url(r"^api/1/", include(router.urls)),]
```

Comment: Help from - https://spapas.github.io/2015/04/29/django-show-404-page/